# VSCode cannot find header files that are on a virtual server

Tags: visual-studio-code, c++

I'm working on some C++ with VSCode. It's for a website and I'm running it locally with Lando. I'm getting errors that VS can't find libraries header files.

I suspect that it's because Lando has downloaded these libraries to it's server and not my project so that's why VS can't see em.

It's not a problem, the site still works, but it makes it a little harder to see what needs fixing as most files have "errors" from these includes. I've also noticed that if the headers have errors, actual errors don't show up as errors which is really dumb.
It's hindering my development quite noticeably.

Is there a way to solve / circumvent this issue? Thanks.

Examples :
Cannot open source file 
Cannot open source file

Comment: Visual Studio Code, C++, and Lando... hrrm.. you don't even give a clue as to what operating system you are using as these three things are supported everywhere.

Comment: Bah, my apologies. Ubuntu 19.04  I've just found the remote-containers extension for vsc but yet to make it work

Comment: You also didn't indicate which header files cannot be found.  We don't need the entire list just enough information to understand the problem you describe.

Comment: I'll include a few but is that actually needed for the problem? These headers are downloaded into Landos container (I believe), thus the app works but vscode cannot see them.